# data communication with multiple clients on a single port

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a java server which uses one port for listening to new connections and creates another port when one client attach to it. This another port is used for data communication with client for which it is created. Each time new user connects , server creates new port. But as we know No. of Ports are limited. So is it possible for server to communicate with multiple clients through single port ?

Thanks,
Arpit

Comment: yes it is possible.try it

Comment: please can you expain how to do it ?

Comment: just google any client server program ... chat program for example